# Typings and inheritance

Tags: typescript

I can create typings for a function `CustomErr` like this:

```
declare class CustomErr extends Error {
    constructor(message: string);
}

function CustomErr(message: string) {
    var err = new Error(message)
    Object.setPrototypeOf(err, CustomErr.prototype)
    return err
}

CustomErr.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
    name: { value: 'Custom Error', enumerable: false }
})

throw new CustomErr("something went wrong") // no error now
```

This works fine until I want to access `CustomErr.message` which exists on `Error`:

> Property 'message' does not exist on type 'CustomErr'.(2339)

How can I fix this?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=23&pln=17&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwMIFdkBcD2AtgKIwzwgAeOIAdsGiTHmQN4BQ8nieNuMmYfDAAUBEKigBzEAC54fAJY1JASgDcbAL5s2AM0w1BCnhmz5ipUeORTZ8nDCWr47LvABuscqXgBeeDQgAO7wjMxWEtIqHFwA8gBGAFbgOAB0yCA4AApM%20DgAngAOILG6wiCkADSmuISMqYW5eAXF0W5wOJgwNN4wWjpYtRYwDU0tCP4JyYKpYHBQ1MJhI43NzUUg1a5cNFBiciweUBCYdgDkg%20ahpMxn1bSYYjBQ8RB2uscZ8Nqa0WxgPFwvT8AWCNXMjGEACJkIRMgALJzwIK0HDIpjKKEqeAAehxATwvWYBKC-0BeDeqQgeEk5VIqTEkRA0SAA)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** since `CustomErr` is a third-party lib that cannot be changed, don't mix code together.

```js
// third-party-lib.js

function CustomErr(message: string) {
    var err = new Error(message)
    Object.setPrototypeOf(err, CustomErr.prototype)
    return err
}

CustomErr.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
    name: { value: 'Custom Error', enumerable: false }
})
```

```js
// third-party-lib.d.ts

declare class CustomErr extends Error {
    constructor(message: string);
}
```

```js
// my-code.ts

const err = new CustomErr("something went wrong") // no error now
console.log(err.message)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because I need to stick with the `CustomErr` function as well.

Comment: May be a TypeScript bug, but why must you stick with it as a function?

Comment: It is from a third party library I need to create typings for.

Comment: Do so in a separate `*.d.ts`, and use it in a separate `*.ts` not mixed with that function thing.